# Random numbers with ratio

Tags: javascript

I want to randomize my list with custom widths. For this, I wrote simple JavaScript snippet generating numbers between `1 and 2`.

Function is as follows:

```
randomizePortfolio: function() {
    $('ul.works').children('li').each(function() {
        var Random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1,
            words = 'normal';
        if(Random == '2') {
            words = 'wide';
        }

        $(this).addClass('col-md-'+3*Random+' col-sm-'+3*Random+' '+words);
    });

    $('ul.works').masonry({
        itemSelector: 'li'
    });
}
```

Problem is, I'd like have bigger ratio for `1`. Now it - obviosly - random, so sometimes I'm getting all `2`'s, some other time - all `1`'s. How can I add ratio (let's say 3:1) to this?

Answer (score 3):

To get a 3:1 distribution you can create an array with the numbers that you want, and add three 1s and one 2, and randomize the index:

```
var rvalues = [1,1,1,2];
var Random = rvalues[Math.floor(Math.random() * rvalues.length)];
```

Here's another, equivalent, method based on the fact that 3/4 of the time the random value is less than 3/4:

```
var Random:
if (Math.random() < .75) Random = 1;
else Random = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. But now I have another problem - I'm getting two `2`'s in a row. Any thoughts on preventing this from happening?

Comment: If you don't want that to happen check if the previous number was 2 and return 1 if it was. Otherwise the probability of getting a 2 is 25% independently of what the previous number was.

Comment: It's not that easy :) If I don't get two `2`s in a row, I' getting something like `2 1 2 1` and this is a problem also (since row is only 4 elements wide). If I start reaching to both prev and next, I'm afraid that there'll be no `2`'s at all.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why is not getting any 2's at all a problem if you are supposed to generate random numbers?

Comment: Let me demonstrate here: http://i.imgur.com/0OvRMS3.jpg You see, row is supposed to have up to four `1`s. When I randomize it, sometimes it works great, sometimes it turns out like the screenshot shows. Fun thing is, I try to use Masonry and it doesn't even help with this ;)

Comment: So what you really want is a random expression of 4 as a sum of 1s and 2s?

Comment: Propably, yes. I was thinking about this, but I have no idea how to get this done.

Comment: There are exactly three ways of doing that: 2+1+1, 1+2+1, and 1+1+2. So you want to choose one of those randomly?

Answer (score 0):

another way, that I'm using, that could make it for you:

```js
// here's the value we wanna get by ratio (where v is value and r is ratio)
// r is an array with min and max value, this example is based on a 100% ratio
const ratioValues = [
  {v: 1, r: [0,75]}, // 75% chance to get 1
  {v: 2, r: [76,100]} // 25% chance to get 2
];
//actual function to get our value
function getRandByRatio(ratioValues) {
  // idx is a random integer between 0 and 100
  let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 + 1));
  for (let item of ratioValues) {
    // test if idx is within the r range
    if (idx >= item.r[0] && idx <= item.r[1]) {
      //if it is return our value
      return item.v;
    }
  }
};

// let's make a testing function
function makeTest(nb) {
  const ul = document.getElementById("rand-value");
  for (let i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
    ul.innerHTML += "<li>" + getRandByRatio(ratioValues) + "</li>";
  }
};

makeTest(10);
```

```html
<ul id="rand-value"></ul>
```

while it might be quite a lot of code for just 2 values, I find it more readable and easier to maintain.(And it's great when you have more values!!!)

Hope this can be usefull to someone!! :)